# Conditional Expectation of an autoregressive (AR1) Process

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, algebra

Suppose X is a time series that follows the process:

$X[t]=\rho X[t-1] + \varepsilon[t]$

where $\varepsilon[t] \sim \mathcal{N}(0.0, \sigma)$, $\varepsilon[t]$ is IID and $X[0] \sim \mathcal{N}(0.0, \sigma)$,.

My interest is computing a conditional expectation using mathematical:

Allowing for notational sloppiness, I want to focus on the subset of $X[t]$ that satisfy:

$$ \tilde{X}[t]\ < Q( X[t] < Q(0.1, X[t]) $$
Where $Q(0.1, X[t])$ is the $0.1$ quantile observation of $X[t]$.

Then find the conditional expectation of $\tilde{X}[t]$:

$$\mathbb{E}[\ \tilde{X}[t] \ |\ ( \tilde{X}[t-3] < Q(0.5, \tilde{X}[t-3]))]  $$

In words, I want to find the subset of the process that falls below the 0.1 quantile observation. Then find the mean of the subset that satisfies the condition before and also had a realization three periods ago that is lower than the median of all observations from three periods for this particular subset of realizations.

Comment: Define AR1.....

Comment: For reference: Autoregressive Model [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) page.

Comment: Should we assume that the $\epsilon_i$'s are all independent (which is implied by the title but not made explicit in the question) and that $X_0\sim N(0,\sigma)$?

Comment: Yep, I added some more information to clarify that.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you wrong information.  The variance of every $X_t$ (including $X_0$) is $\sigma^2/(1-\rho^2)$.  But that means $Q(0.05, X_t)$ is always less than $Q(0.10, X_{t-3})$.  So is the conditioning you've written really what you want?

Comment: I want to emphasize that $X_0 \sim N(0,\sigma/\sqrt{1-\rho^2})$ (which is the value in the link given by @Syed) which means that $E(X_t | X_{t-3} < 0)$ is $-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \rho ^3 \sigma }{\sqrt{1-\rho ^2}}$.  (I haven't got a closed-form for when $1/10=0.1$ is used.)

Answer (score 1):

If in *Mathematica* terms by $Q(0.05, X_t)$ you mean

```
x = InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, σ/Sqrt[1 - ρ^2]], 1/20]
```

then because the marginal distributions of the $X_i$ are all normal with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2/(1-\rho^2)$, $Q(0.05, X_t)$ is always less than $Q(0.10, X_{t-3})$, then mean of $X_t$ conditional on $X_t < x$ is found with

```
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{-∞, InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, σ/Sqrt[1 - ρ^2]], 1/20]},
  NormalDistribution[0, σ/Sqrt[1 - ρ^2]]]
Mean[dist]
```

[image: Conditional mean]

But I suspect this is not the conditioning you want.

Comment: You are right Jim. Thinking about it some more, I am after something that is definitely not like this.  

What I want to compute is a conditional expectation. 

I first want to focus on $X_t$ less than $Q(0.1,X_t)$ .

So let's define these as: $$\tilde{X_t} < Q(0.1, X_t)$$

Then the object I am interested in can be summarised in sloppy notation as:
$$\mathbb{E}_t[ \tilde{X_t} \ |  \ \tilde{X}_{t-3} \ < \ Q(0.5, \tilde{X}_{t-3}) ]  $$

Comment: Sounds good.  Editing your question to reflect that would be helpful to others.  In short, $X_t$ and $X_{t-3}$ will have a bivariate normal distribution so that conditional expectation will be easy to obtain.